# ANR Input dispatching timed out

Tags: android, android-anr-dialog

**ANR Input dispatching timed out (Waiting to send non-key event because the touched window has not finished processing certain input events that were delivered to it over 500.0ms ago. Wait queue length: 60. Wait queue head age: 8503.2ms.)**

Hi! I'm getting this strange ANR-report from several users. Unfortunately, I have very limited knowledge about ANR-reports, and I'm hoping that someone can help me to understand what the cause of this could be

```
"main" prio=5 tid=1 Suspended
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x74a20f90 self=0x557fe6f9d0
| sysTid=23849 nice=1 cgrp=top_visible sched=0/0 handle=0x7faf4f5000
| state=S schedstat=( 79111961552 2206905376 39235 ) utm=7534 stm=377 core=7 HZ=100
| stack=0x7fdaaf0000-0x7fdaaf2000 stackSize=8MB
| held mutexes=
at android.os.MessageQueue.removeMessages(MessageQueue.java:682)
- locked <0x08f02647> (a android.os.MessageQueue)
at android.os.Handler.removeMessages(Handler.java:652)
at android.view.Choreographer.removeCallbacksInternal(Choreographer.java:418)
- locked <0x0bd41e74> (a java.lang.Object)
at android.view.Choreographer.removeCallbacks(Choreographer.java:406)
at android.view.View.removeCallbacks(View.java:13179)
at android.support.v4.widget.aa.a(unavailable:-1)
at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.a(unavailable:-1)
at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onInterceptTouchEvent(unavailable:-1)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2108)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2525)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2525)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2525)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2525)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2525)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2525)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2525)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2461)
at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1777)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2865)
at android.support.v7.view.n.dispatchTouchEvent(unavailable:-1)
at android.support.v7.view.n.dispatchTouchEvent(unavailable:-1)
at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2422)
at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:9610)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4436)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4302)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3836)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3889)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3855)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3981)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3863)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4038)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3836)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3889)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3855)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3863)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3836)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6135)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:6109)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6070)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6251)
at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:192)
at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native method)
at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:330)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5546)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(Native method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:794)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:684)
```

Comment: ANR activity not responding. Probably you are doing too much work in the main thread

Comment: The thing is that I'm not doing much work on main thread (as I know of) - although I'm using viewpager with a Google maps mapfragment - could maybe be that the mapfragment is loading a lot of custom tiles although it is not visible?

Comment: is the mapfragment visible when you get the ANR? if not, you can try saying to the viewpager how many pages it should cache or maybe to load an empty fragment in order to check if the problem is the mapfragment

Comment: Hello, I had the same issue with having the list of ExoPlayer, This ANR is produced only on MotoG4 device. In all other devices, it perfectly working.Error: Reason: Input dispatching timed out (Waiting to send non-key event because the touched window has not finished processing certain input events that were delivered to it over 500.0ms ago.  Wait queue length: 8.  Wait queue head age: 5766.3ms.)

Comment: I got this exception when attached a debugger. Then opened a new screen (from Compose list). Without debugger it opens faster and without exception.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This happened to me when I had a loop and there was a condition for the loop to get incremented. I had not set the increment for when the condition was not met. Hence, the loop stalled. This resulted in the above error.

Without your code, I cannot help. But the above is a possible cause of your error.

Answer (score 9):

Obviously, you anr log is not complete. It only shows main thread log, what else
thread log.

In main thread, from this `"main" prio=5 tid=1 Suspended`, we know the thread was suspended. Before that, it
`- locked <0x08f02647> (a android.os.MessageQueue) at android.os.Handler.removeMessages(Handler.java:652) at android.view.Choreographer.removeCallbacksInternal(Choreographer.java:418)`
`- locked <0x0bd41e74> (a java.lang.Object)`

You should search the log to check which thread waiting to lock the  <0x08f02647> and <0x0bd41e74>, the you may find some clue.